# Reference system with all grid lines being great circles

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing

I was thinking of a problem where it might be easier if instead of latitude (and parallels) we would have a system with an additional east/west pole and great circles through them would provide a second coordinate to go along with longitude.

Was thinking surely this has been done before, but I'm missing a name for such a reference system.

Is this known/used and by what name so I can read more?

edit: a sketch as requested:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of what you imagine?

Comment: Did you read this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366890/concept-behind-longitudes/366897#366897
It does not answer your question, but for the reasons explained there, I doubt that anyone has seriously conceptualized such a coordiante system.

Comment: @babel I'm thinking in the opposite direction of that question, not make lines of longitude parallel but the other wide around replace lines of equal latitude with great circles. Though both aim to increase symmetry between the two coordinates.

Comment: It's just that I simply have difficulties to image what benefit such a system would have, what would be the advantage of it. For that I'm not sure if such a system was ever conceived. But curious to learn...

Comment: What you have in your picture does not appear to be  lines of equal latitude (the red ones). The parallel lines of latidute have the same latitude everywhere: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Latitude_lines.svg/440px-Latitude_lines.svg.png

Comment: Yes the point was to only use great circles. This coordinate system would not use longitude and latitude but rather longitude and not-latitude whatever you want to call the red lines(which unlike parallels are all great circles)

Comment: You would run into a number of issues with such a system. For instance, consider the great circle arc from your fictitious East Pole to the North Pole. Any point on that arc would be ambiguous, because their longitude would be the same, and their 'pseudo-latitude' would also be the same. There would be no way to define a point on that arc unless you resort to normal latitudes.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed a problematic scenario. not necessarily fatal in my use case but sufficient to convince me it's probably not a well known system I will find plenty to read on.

Comment: At an arbitrary point on Earth there are two directions that intersect perpendicularly. The directions of the meridian and the parallel that pass through the point. In classical cartography this property is very important. Your system loses that property, but cartography will also cease to be classical. I don't know if the system you're referring to exists, but you'll need some new cartographic theorems to replace the old ones.